# How to add boostrap into messages in django

Tags: django-templates

I create a form and if the form had any error from the user, I add a django message in the template. It works but it only show the text. I want to highlight it as an error message but I don't know how to add boostrap to message.

I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the message in a  and give boostrap class as usual.

```
<dev class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                {{ message }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Django display Bootstrap Messges in Web Page

#### Steps:

```py
       # 1 - Add Code in (setting.py)


       from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
    
        MESSAGE_TAGS = {
            messages.DEBUG: 'alert-info',
            messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
            messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
            messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
            messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
        }
    
        # 2 - Add Code in (html.page) for message display


        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```